# jquery focus and blur function but also if val is not equal to null.

Tags: jquery, html, input, focus, blur

I am trying to modify the background of an input based on the focus and blur events. That part works fine, but I also want to set the background if the client has entered a value into the search box. It does work if you enter text and then immediately click the submit button (although you can see the background change very briefly).

But if a value is currently in the search box AND the client triggers the blur function, it also changes the background of the input.

How can I ensure that the blur function is not triggered if there is a value in the search box?

This is my code so to date:

```
 // change input field on blur and focus
var $searchFocus = 'url("img/layout/spyglass.png") no-repeat 2px 0 #FFFFFF';
var $searchBlur = 'url("img/layout/spyglass-text.png") no-repeat 2px 0 #FFFFFF';
$('#query').css('background', $searchBlur);

if($('#query').val() !='') {
    $('#query').css('background', $searchFocus);
}

$('#query').focus(function(){
    $('#query').css('background', $searchFocus);
}); 

$('#query').blur(function() {
    $('#query').css('background', $searchBlur);
});
```

I've made a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lharby/e6uTB/)

Maybe I want something different to the blur function?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious solution is to simply test the value within the blur function.

However, your question explicitly states that the blur function should only be triggered if the value is empty.

This solution adds and removes the blur function when the value is changed.

```
function setSearchBackground() {
     $('#query').css('background', $searchBlur);  
}

$('#query').on('blur', setSearchBackground);


$('#query').change(function() {
    if($(this).val() == '') {
        $(this).on('blur', setSearchBackground);
    } else {
        $(this).off('blur', setSearchBackground);
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sUtTp/

Personally, I would solve the problem as Kyle has described, and perform the value check within the `blur` function.

Answer (score 4):

For your blur:

```
$('#query').blur(function() {
    if(!$('#query').val()) $('#query').css('background', $searchBlur);
});
```

Updated working fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/e6uTB/3/

---

**UPDATE**

As an added bonus, I refactored your code!

http://jsfiddle.net/e6uTB/8/

Comment: Excellent, great work, I thought about an OR statement, but this does the job. Thank you.

Comment: No problem, check out the refactoring I did for you, too. It'll save you time down the road